# Creating packet sniffer in c++

Tags: python, c++, sockets, communication

I have before created a simple packet sniffer using python, with the following code:

```
import socket
import os
import time

host = "192.168.0.164"

if os.name == "nt":
    socket_protocol = socket.IPPROTO_IP
else:
    socket_protocol = socket.IPPROTO_ICMP

while True:
    sniffer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket_protocol)

    sniffer.bind((host, 0))

    sniffer.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)

    sniffer.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)

    out = sniffer.recvfrom(65565)

    print("recieved {0} bytes from: {1}:{2}".format(len(out[0]), out[1][0], out[1][1]))

    sniffer.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_OFF)
```

In a loop it prints out the size in bytes of the recieved packet data and the ip adress of the sender and port.
Im trying to recreate this program using c++ and this is what i have go so far:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <Mstcpip.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

#define PORT 0

struct sockaddr_in address;

SOCKET sock;

const char opt = 0;

u_long mode_on = RCVALL_ON;

u_long mode_off = RCVALL_OFF;

char buffer;

int main()
{

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IP);

    setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &opt, sizeof(opt));

    bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*) & address, sizeof(address));
    ioctlsocket(sock, SIO_RCVALL, &mode_on);

    recv(sock, &buffer, 65565, 0);

    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;

    ioctlsocket(sock, SIO_RCVALL, &mode_off);

    return 0;
}
```

I am not very familiar with socket programming in c++.
When i run the program no output is being printed out.
I have tried running the program in a loop to see if it just was that there wasnt any incoming packet at exactly that time but still no luck.
There are no errors occuring when i run the program.

Comment: `std::cout << buffer << std::endl;` -- If `buffer` contains embedded nulls, this will not output all the information.  Your code also fails to process any return values, like from the `recv`.

Comment: I'm no expert on socket programming but the first thing I would do is give your program a chance to print some error messages by checking the return values of the various functions you call. If any of them return an error code that gives you more chance to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie There is nothing being outputed at all. and i have tried converting the buffer to other types and printing it out, it is always null.

Comment: Which brings up the point of not processing the [recv return value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recv).  That function returns to you the number of bytes received, or an error code.  Also, python and C++ are two different languages -- don't try to use python as a model in writing C++ code -- it will only make things more confusing.

Comment: And if `recv` returns the number of bytes and you don't see any information, that is because you are using the wrong output routines to view the values.  Your `std::cout << buffer` is designed to stop at the first null byte, regardless if `buffer` has information.

Comment: I tried to us WSAGetLastError() to get the last error from the program, and it is WSANOTINITIALISED (10093), "Successful WSAStartup not yet performed.
    Either the application has not called WSAStartup or WSAStartup failed. The application may be accessing a socket that the current active task does not own (that is, trying to share a socket between tasks), or WSACleanup has been called too many times." from microsoft, im not sure what i should do in that case.

Comment: Winsock requires you to call the requisite [startup functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/initializing-winsock).  I suggest you go through the Winsock examples, since you are making several mistakes with your code (the 3 already pointed out).  I can understand if you got the code from a non-Winsock environment, where there is no initialization needed to be done, but even with that, the `recv` code is still wrong or poorly written (it should also be in a `for` loop until no more information is received).

Comment: Thanks, that worked, the error is now gone, though the is another error now 10038.

Comment: 10038 = 0x00002736 = `WSAENOTSOCK`, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/18d8fbe8-a967-4f1c-ae50-99ca8e491d2d

Comment: Just look at this code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/complete-server-code It does all error handling, initializes WinSock, closes socket at the end, uses received bytes return value

Comment: Thanks, i will have a look at the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you review some complete examples of configuring and reading from a socket.  The example provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recv) appears to be not only complete, but the page specifies expected return values for the receive function.

Additionally, you are not initializing your buffer properly.  You are essentially allotting 8 bits of data, then telling the receive function that it has 65565 bytes to fill (did you mean 2^16 which would give you 65536 (or 65535 accounting for buffer zero based indexing)?).

One last thing: the code which you provided in python appears to be intended to work on multiple platforms, but the C++ code will only compile for Windows.  I would recommend focusing on getting this to work on a single platform before attempting to transfer it to any others.